# Error loading association from controller in cakephp

Tags: join, cakephp-3.0

I can't get this simple query right. I need to join my `adresses` table to my `annonces` table.

I supose this should be farly strait forward but I simply can't get it to work.

I firstly made my `adresse` table object like this

```
class AdressesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {                                   
        $this->belongsTo('Annonces', [
                                    'foreignKey' => 'annonceId',
                                    'joinType' => 'INNER',
                                ]);
    }
}
```

Then in my annonces controller I tryed to join the adresses like this

```
public function view($id = null)
{
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Annonce invalide!'));
    }
    $query = $this->Annonces->find('all', ['contain' => ['Adresses']])->where(['id' => $id]);
    $annonce = $query->firstOrFail();
    $this->set(compact('annonce'));
}
```

But then I got this error :

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Adresses.annonce_id' in 'where clause'
```

Witch I don't understand why I got it since I have defined my foreign key in the `AdressesTable class`.

The query I would like to have at the end would look like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM annonces
INNER JOIN adresses ON adresses.annonceId = annonces.id
WHERE annonces.id = @param
```

*PS. I know it wont be select * but rather select [all my column]*

EDIT : My table schema are as following

```
CREATE TABLE annonces(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,     #PK
    startDate DATE NOT NULL,
    endDate DATE NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    descript TEXT NOT NULL,
    infoSupplementaire TEXT NULL,
    premium BIT NOT NULL,
    clientId INT NOT NULL,              #FK
    categorieId INT NOT NULL,           #FK

    CONSTRAINT pk_annonces_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_annonces_clientId FOREIGN KEY (clientId) REFERENCES clients(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_annonces_categorieId FOREIGN KEY (categorieId) REFERENCES categories(id)
);

CREATE TABLE adresses(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,     #PK
    latitude DECIMAL(11,7),
    longitude DECIMAL(11,7),
    adresse VARCHAR(512),
    annonceId INT NOT NULL,             #FK

    CONSTRAINT pk_adresses_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_adresses_annonceId FOREIGN KEY (annonceId) REFERENCES annonces(id)
)
```

**I solved my problem by renaming my column folowing cakephp convention and using any of the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30686081/2145522)**

Comment: For the sake of completeness, the problem is most likely to be found in the `hasMany` or `hasOne` (not entirely sure what you are using) association of your `AnnoncesTable` class, as that is what is being taken into consideration when querying from that table. The `belongsTo` association is only used when querying from the other table, ie from `AdressesTable`.

Comment: I will post the hasmany relation when i will be back home. I'm alway willing to learn more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
$query = $this->Annonces->find('all', ['contain' => ['Adresses']])->where(['Annonces.id' => $id]);
$annonce = $query->firstOrFail();
```

OR

```
public function view($id = null)
{
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Annonce invalide!'));
    }
    $annonceEntity = $this->Annonces->get($id);

    $query = $this->Annonces->find('all', ['contain' => ['Adresses']])->where(['Annonces.id' => $annonceEntity->id]);
    $annonce = $query->firstOrFail();
    $this->set(compact('annonce'));
}
```

Comment: nether of them work :( I'm currently trying to rename all my FK to match the standard cakephp way I will retry after that. Thank you

Comment: can you share your tables? The code followed cake convention. If you do, it would work for sure.. Thanks

Comment: I added the two table in the question

Comment: Please change **annonceId** to **annonce_id** from adresses Table and then make the associations are as follows `$this->hasMany('Adresses', ['foreignKey' => 'annonce_id']);` at AnnonceeTable and `$this->belongsTo('Annonces', ['foreignKey' => 'annonce_id', 'joinType' => 'INNER']);` at AdressesTable . It is working at My PC

Comment: After I changed to the standard cakephp way (as you suggest in you comment) It worked like a charm thank you